# Matlab builder NE 2012A x64 migreting to 2014B X64

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to convert my system from matlab 2012a x64 to matlab 2014b x64. However I'm getting this error. i'm using .Net 4.5, visual studio 2012 + update 5.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in MWArray.dll
Additional information: Start-up options discovered in multiple assembiles.
```

then I hit F5 and I get:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in MWArray.dll
Additional information: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception.
```

I press F5 again and I get:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in MWArray.dll
Additional information: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception.
```

here is my code:

```
private static MWArray ConvertBlackLevelResultsToMWArray(BlackLevelData blackLevelData)
      {
          var blackLevelResultsGroupedbyExposure = from blResult in blackLevelData group blResult by blResult.ExposureTime;
          var exposuresCount = blackLevelResultsGroupedbyExposure.Count();
            var blackLevelCells = new MWCellArray(1, exposuresCount); //the exception is here
```

I have used .net reflector in order to go over all of the dependencies in other DLL files, they all have refernce to the correct MWarray version 2.14.1.0

Can you suggest A way to find out what is my problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove all the attributes

```
[assembly: MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCROption ("- nojit")]
```

from all places, to which were added for MCR 2012a.

Comment: Crazy that i didn't even remember that